# Are DAOs still needed in Spring MVC with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I know that this question has been asked countless times, but since most of the questions on this subject are 6-7 years old, I was hoping to see if there are any changes in the original arguments for/against this topic as newer versions of JPA came out. I know that this can be seen as primarily opinion based, but I am looking for a list of pros/cons.

Some people have argued that the entitymanager is a DAO in and of itself, and that a DAO layer in your application would be redundant. Most people would agree that the `EntityManager` covers basic CRUD operations very tightly...but there is a point that we should not be using `entitymanager.createQuery(...)` inside the service layer.

But now with the `@NamedQueries` annotation, we can simply add named queries to the model class and maintain a set of custom criteria queries for each entity model. For example, if we had a `User` class we can have something like

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="User.findByUsername", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username_lowercase = LOWER(:username)")
})
public class User{

@Column
private String username;

}
```

By storing the custom criteria queries inside of the model classes, we can avoid re-writing the same queries over and over again in the service layer - which makes the DAO layer seem even more unnecessary now.

The reasons that I have found to include the DAO layer are now:

- You can change the persistence mechanism in the future more easily by having a central point that maintains data access (i.e generic DAO)
- Easier time unit testing

I was wondering if anyone could contribute to this list as I am not sure if I should be using a DAO layer in my application

Comment: *Are DAOs still needed in Spring MVC with JPA/Hibernate*, actually they have **never** been needed, check this [**Spring MVC Architecture** article](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/understanding-spring-mvc?start=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, my assumption is that people who argued that the `EntityManager` is a DAO, injects entity manager directly to their services and manipulating it from there.

So as far as they are using just crud operations —  `EntityManager` + `@NamedQueries` approach is good enough.

But once they put an extra logic say pagination or some security checks or projections to a some sort of DTO's (just to avoid fetching of unnecessary fields) they will reinvent the `DAO` within service layer and as you mentioned this piece of logic has to be tested and it has to be decoupled in some way.

So if you have only CRUD-style application, you can just omit using `DAO` layer and it is fine, but try to think a little bit upfront and predict possible complications.

Comment: I have to agree, as soon as you go a bit *beyond* simple applications its inevitable. 1+